# Elements CombinerParameters and CombinerParameter in XACML

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, abac

I am reading the XACML Standard and I see this elements, but the documentation is very technical and I can't find examples about these elements.

What do the elements `CombinerParameters` and `CombinerParameter` do in XACML?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your specific question? What documentation are you referring to? Did you check out Wikipedia?

Answer (score 0):

### Background

The XACML ([xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml)) core specification is defined by OASIS and can be found [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html). XACML is a language that implements attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)).

The specification defines:

1. An architecture
2. A policy language
3. A means to send authorization requests and receive authorization responses

### Language Elements - Combiner Parameters

Your question relates to the language itself. The language contains many different elements of which:

- CombinerParameter (defined [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047122))
- CombinerParameters (defined [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047121))

Combiner parameters are used in conjunction with combining algorithms.

### What is a combining algorithm?

When a `policyset` or a `policy` element contain multiple children, these children can be conflicting. For instance a policy could contain the following rules:

- Managers can view documents in their department
- Managers cannot view secret documents

These 2 rules are conflicting. Which one wins? This is where combining algorithms step in ([Specification definition](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047077) | [Blog post](https://www.axiomatics.com/blog/entry/understanding-xacml-combining-algorithms.html) | [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML#Combining_algorithms)). Combining algorithms help determine which policies and rules win. For instance, deny-overrides makes deny decisions win over permit decisions.

Combining algorithms in XACML can have *combiner parameters* to influence the way they work. **Note that none of the default combining algorithms defined in the specification use combiner parameters.** If you wanted to, you could implement a custom combining algorithm that would make use of combiner parameters.

### The combiner parameters in detail

The first element contains any number of the second element as defined hereafter:

```
<xs:element name="CombinerParameters" type="xacml:CombinerParametersType"/>
<xs:complexType name="CombinerParametersType">
   <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="xacml:CombinerParameter" minOccurs="0"
               maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The second element is defined as follows

```
<xs:element name="CombinerParameter" type="xacml:CombinerParameterType"/>
<xs:complexType name="CombinerParameterType">
   <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="xacml:AttributeValue"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="ParameterName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

It contains:

- a sequence of attribute values
- a parameter name e.g. `location`.

An attribute value is made up of:

- a value e.g. `Chicago`
- a datatype e.g. `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string`

An example attribute value in XML looks like the following:

```
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Chicago</AttributeValue>
```

In other words, a combiner parameter is:

- an identifier e.g. location
- a value made up a the value itself e.g. 'Chicago' and the datatype e.g. string.